# Is there a tendency for presidents to come from outside of "big politics" in recent years?

Tags: president, presidential-election

According to [this article](http://www.mischiefsoffaction.com/2015/08/have-we-ever-elected-president-who-has.html) which is based on [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Presidents_of_the_United_States_by_previous_experience)

> Donald Trump has never been elected to public office (a big
>   disqualifier in American politics), never been appointed to a
>   political office, and has no military experience. He is a businessman.
>   We have had presidents who have had previous careers in business
>   (e.g., Harding, Truman, both Bushes), but none who have gone straight
>   from business to being elected President.

So, USA has a president with little previous political experience.

Emmanuel Macron has more political experience than Trump, yet his background is more about investment banking ([source](http://heavy.com/news/2017/04/emmanuel-macron-political-policy-positions-platform-campaign-france/)) rather than politics where he started to play an important role since 2012:

> From 2012 to 2014, he served as deputy secretary-general of the
>   Élysée, a senior role in President Hollande's staff. He was
>   appointed as the Minister of Economy and Finance in the second Valls
>   Cabinet on 26 August 2014, replacing Arnaud Montebourg. As
>   Minister of the Economy, Macron was at the forefront of pushing
>   through business-friendly reforms. On 17 February 2015, prime minister
>   Manuel Valls pushed Macron's signature law package through a reluctant
>   parliament using the special 49.3 procedure.

At the moment of writing this question, he has to face Marine Le Pen in the run-off election on May 7th, having the first chance by many polls (thus including him in list).

Going even more to the East, in Romania, a East European country, current president is [Klaus Iohannis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Klaus_Iohannis#Political_career), who had rather little political experience before being elected as President (he had much more experience in local administration):

> On February 20, **2013**, Klaus Iohannis joined the PNL [...] (the
>   largest opposition party)

So, he acquired a role in the "big politics" just a few years before being elected as President.

**Question:** **Is there a tendency for presidents to be outside of "big politics" in recent years? Or am I observing only some isolated cases?**

Comment: Obama was elected in 2008 and was only a federal Senator for a short bit before that. I won't bother going as far back as TR.